# Como editar arquivo host no etc/hosts?

Tags: linux

Como editar arquivo host no `etc/hosts`?

O *site* é de fora, então eu adicionei o ip: `xxx.xxxx.xxx` `www.meusite.com.br`

Porem quando vou dar um *ping* ou escanear para ver os servidores, ele não encontra nenhum sinal.

Comment: Tu pode consultar o manual desse arquivo digitando no terminal: `man 5 hosts`. Ve se te ajuda em algo.

Comment: Qual o retorno do ping?

Answer (score 1):

A sintaxe do arquivo /etc/hosts é a seguinte:

```
# Endereço IP      Nome "completo" do host       Apelido (opcional)
10.10.10.10        www.meusite.com.br            meusite
```

Seguindo esse padrão, é para funcionar. Lembrando que você deve editar o arquivo como root (ou usando o comando "sudo" para chamar o editor):

```
$ sudo vim /etc/hosts
```

O resultado deve ser o seguinte:

```
$ ping -c3 www.meusite.com.br
PING www.meusite.com.br (10.10.10.10) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.10.10.10 (10.10.10.10): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=18.0 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.10 (10.10.10.10): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=19.0 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.10.10 (10.10.10.10): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=19.0 ms
--- www.meusite.com.br ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2045ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.028/0.039/0.059/0.013 ms

$ getent hosts meusite
10.10.10.10    www.meusite.com.br     meusite
```

Verifique se você seguiu esse padrão e faça os testes acima para validar as alterações.

Espero que isso ajude.